# What is this effect called? 'Grow/shrink'? 'Fly-out/fly-in'? 

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have seen links that open modal windows AND have a nice animation effect that create the illusion that the window grows out of the link clicked. On closing the window a similar animation shows that the window shrinks and disappears in the link which originally opened it. I remember I saw it on some jquery page but don't remember where and don't know what this effect is called.

Have you seen this? Examples?

Comment: sure this is not some kind of tooltip!?

Comment: Eureka! I found the original link: [http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/windows.html](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/windows.html). But still don't know what (if any) the animation is called.

Comment: @aSeptik: No, just take a look at the example in the link and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a custom animation using the .animate() function, probably expanding height and width.

Comment: It may well be possible to simulate this with .animate(), but the author, Stefan Petre, has written his custom helper function for this. By the way, many UI functionality has been achieved by this genius back in 2006! I wonder if jQuery UI has used the same code or just has `borrowed` ideas.

Comment: danspants, you're right. Inside the custom helper function `.animate()` is used. --- And here is some additional info: 
The page featuring this is part of [interface package by Stefan Petre](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/windows.html). The author, in code, calls the effect `TransferTo` and the helper could be found in source in `ifxtransfer.js` file.

Comment: Thanks for the .animate hint. I was looking for something else but a faked 'shrink/grow' with .animate could work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is actually called "grow" and "shrink".

Here's an example: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/grow.html

Comment: No, webdestroya, that is not it (the link), so far searches with `grow shrink modal link` have not led me to something like I'd seen

Answer (score 0):

nyroModal has a similar grow/shrink animation when you click links, but it doesn't fly out of the link you clicked if that is what you mean

you can check it out at http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/

Answer (score 0):

The page featuring this is part of [interface package by Stefan Petre](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/windows.html). The author, in code, calls the effect `TransferTo` and the helper could be found in source in `ifxtransfer.js` file.